# Remote Server, php, MySQL connection within an iPhone app

Tags: php, iphone, mysql

I have found many places online that say in order connect to a remote MYSql database, use php.  I do not know how to get from my iphone app, to php, to mysql and back.  I cannot seem to find anything on the relationship of these things.  I would really really appreciate any help in this matter.  Where do I write the php code?  Where do I call it?  When do I connect to the remote server.  I am new to this task.

please help

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To try and answer the question, the way this kind of access works is that you would create a web service with PHP code on a web server. This accesses the MySQL database. Your iPhone application would then make a request to your PHP web service and handle the results.

Perhaps you would find this tool of use. I'm involved in a project for allowing you to manage a hosted MySQL database, create a web service layer for it, and build a customised client library that helps you consume the results on the iPhone. The project has just gone into an open beta programme.

It's called Kumulos and it removes all the tricky, repetitive stuff associated with creating database driven apps. We're looking for beta testers and would love to hear your feedback!

You can take a look at the project here: [Creating iPhone MySQL databases with Kumulos](http://www.kumulos.com/)

I hope this has been of some use, thanks,
  Chris